# Schematic diagram of a double-balanced Gilbert cell mixer

Tags: mosfet, rf, mixer, gilbert-cell

For the following gilbert cell circuit, I have few questions.

I understand that R1 to R4 as well as M1 to M6 are parts of the double-balanced differential topology which helps to eliminate the DC component in RF and LO incoming signals, such that there would not be RF and LO feedthrough in the mixer output.

1) What is the purpose of the small-signal current source io ?

2) What are the purposes of M7, M8, R5 and R6 ?

[image: gilbert cell schematics]

Comment: I think it would help you if you would study the venerable MC1496 and associated application nodes, I think.  Most of this becomes clear as you read through. Also, though lower case is used in your schematic, \$i_0\$ isn't a small (differential) signal. It's something you set, which you'll see in the MC1496 plain as day.

Comment: @jonk there is not much information to be extracted from the [MC1496 documentation section on doubly balanced mixer](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC1496-D.PDF#page=10)

Comment: I said ***study*** not *read*. I was considering an answer, but I just don't have the time. So I hoped a reference would help. I learned a lot studying that part in detail. In any case, \$i_0\$ still isn't a differential but instead a finite current. I believe much hinges if you fail to understand that.

Comment: @jonk you mean io is a **DC** bias current ?

Comment: So far as I'm aware it a ***set*** current, not a bias current. But I'm just a meager hobbyist. So what do I know?

Comment: Without Io, there is no current, no charge flowing, to chop. The bandwidth largely is set by the size of Io.

Comment: Yes, \$ i_o \$ is a **DC bias current** - it sets the quiescent operating point for the whole chain of M1 through M6. Be aware that input DC voltage of M1 & M2 gates must be set to a voltage lower than DC voltage of M3,M4,M5,M6 gates. M7 & M8 are really not part of the mixing process - they are simply linear buffers, duplicating the mixer's output (\$V_{outp} - V_{outn} \$ ).